# Possible to have a IF/ELSE STATEMENT inside of data() return

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I get `data` back from my API when some `parameters` are correct.

Now I need to check if I have some data inside of `current_data` or not and want to change the definition of my `array` as you can see below.

Actually what I have tried didn't work, so it would be a big pleasure if someone can help me out!

My error: `if(current_data != null)` gives me multiple errors that it's not a expected declaration.

```
mounted() {
  get_Data() {
    var url = "justexample/API"
    
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        this.current_data = data;
      })
```

```
data() {
  return {
    current_data: [],
    //Here I want to check if current data == [] like this:

    if(current_data != null) {
      array: [{
        id: this.id +=1,
        name: "",
      }]
    } else if(current_data == null {
      array: []
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't compare two different array objects using `==`. Do some research into how to compare arrays

Answer (score 2):

First of all when posting questions: what didn't work? Did you get any errors?

You can't put logic/`if`s in an object returned by the `data` function!
You probably have to put your `if` into a computed:

```
data() {
....
},
computed: {
    counter() {
        return this.current_data?.length > 0 ? 1 : 0; // if the current_data array has 0 items return 0, otherwise 1
    }
}
```

Then you can use the `counter` computed in the template:
`<span>{{ counter }}</span>`

Comment: updated my question hopefully it's clear now.

Comment: Regarding your question: you can't put logic/`if`s in an object returned by the `data` function. This probably also causes the errors --> it's simply not valid syntax.
This is why I recommended that you use a computed.

Respectfully, you should consider learning a thing or two on vanilla Javascript and Vue before trying to implement APIs etc.

Comment: Respectfully, I know working with APIs and all worked well. This is just a question and if it's not possible I will search for another solution for me. I know that I can't put logic in there and because of that I just want to ask if there is a solution for this. Thanks for trying helping me out!

Answer (score -1):

You can do like that:

```
data() {
  return {
    current_data: [],
     //Here I want to check if current data == [] like this:

    counter: null;
  }
}

mounted() {
  get_Data() {
    var url = "justexample/API"

  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => {
     return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    this.current_data = data;
    
    if(current_data == []){
      this.counter = 0
    }
    } else if(current_data != [] {
      this.counter = 1
    }
   })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This 1. doesn't work (`current_data === []`) 2. is bad practice for Vue and 3. doesn't add any information on why people should do it this way.